# How to fetch data from a text file using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file, where I have lots of information, but I only want the ones which starts like this:

```
1. #BEGIN_DRUGCARD DB00001

2. # Generic_Name:
Lepirudin
```

I want to get in the first case what is starts with DB00001.
In the second case, what is in the second line, then save both of them in to a text file.

I have the following script, but it's not working, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viki/workspace/prbb/drugnames", line 22, in 
    drug_id = line()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Any ideas?

```
import re    

regex1 = '#BEGIN_DRUGCARD '
regex2 = '# Generic_Name:'

x=y=0

e = open ('drugbank.txt', 'r')
f = open ('Drug_output.txt', 'w')

for line in e.readlines():

    if re.match(regex1, line):
        y=1
        continue

    elif re.match(regex2, line):
        x=1
        continue

if y==1:
    drug_id = line()

if x==1:
    generic_name = line.split()

f.write('drug_id')
f.write('\n\n')
f.write('generic_name')
```

Comment: I fixed some of your identations, but you should really look over your syntax and/or structure.

Comment: "not quite working well"? Please tell us the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: I get this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viki/workspace/prbb/drugnames", line 22, in <module>
    drug_id = line()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line()` means "call the function named `line`", and of course this can't work because `line` is a string.

But there are several other problems with your code as well. It will only find the last matches in your `drugbank.txt` file because it overwrites all the previous cases before writing anything to the file, and when it's writing something, it's writing the text `drug_id` instead of the contents of the variable `drug_id`). Also, you're using `split()` wrong. Have you read a Python tutorial?

Assuming that your `drugbank.txt` contains several drugs, and that each drug's ID and generic name always follow each other, you could do the job like this:

```
import re    
regex = r'#BEGIN_DRUGCARD\s*(.*)\s*# Generic_Name:\s*(.*)'

with open ('drugbank.txt', 'r') as infile:
    drugs = infile.read()
    results = re.findall(regex,drugs)

with open('Drug_output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for match in results:
        outfile.write(match[0] + "\n" + match[1] + "\n\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I am a very beginner, and I was struggling with this script for a while. I tried your script and I don't get any error message, but the output file is empty.